# Cardinality vs Dimension of a Subset

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

**edited (and answered):**

Suppose I have a subset of **R**. I know this is a subset of the span of $1$ (or any other real number).

My question was: Is there a concept that the subset {$1,3,4$} is "bigger"  than the subset {$7,15$}?

---

The concept I was looking for was cardinality, which allows us to distinguish relative sizes of sets. 
The cardinality of {$1,3,4$} is $3$, the cardinality of {$7,15$} is $2$.

As pointed out below by AngryAvian, the concept of dimensions allows us to distinguish the relative sizes of spaces, all (non-zero) subsets of a space have the same dimension.

Comment: What does it mean to say that a subset is "spanned by $\{1\}$"?

Comment: that every element of the subset is a linear combination of {1}

Comment: But $\mathbb R$ is one dimensional.  Every non-zero element "spans" the entire space.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  It's really not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ have the same dimension, even though some subsets are clearly "bigger."

How are you defining "dimension" for an arbitrary subset? In linear algebra, dimension is only defined for *subspaces*. The only subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$ are $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

> Is there a concept of a basis that spans *only* a subset of the entire space?

A basis of a [finite-dimensional] vector space, by definition, must span the entire space.

> I know $\{1, 7, 17, 21\}$ is spanned by $\{1\}$.

The span of some set of vectors is, by definition, a subspace, so the above statement does not make sense. One might instead say "$\{1, 7, 17, 21\}$ is a subset of the span of $\{1\}$."

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was confusing cardinaliltyband dimension. One thing, does a basis of an infinite-dimensional vector space not need to span the entire space?

Comment: @Jess For infinite-dimensional vector spaces, the definition is still the same (so I could probably have removed "[finite-dimensional]"), and in that context it is sometimes called a "Hamel basis," to distinguish it from other different notions of "basis" that are sometimes more useful in those contexts. See [the "Analysis" subsection of this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)#Analysis) for more details.